# GMFBridge setup in CLR C++

Tags: c++, clr, directshow

I am trying to create a C++ form using CLR for webcame capture. I want to use Directshow and GMFBridge on it so that i can capture and preview video, but im not sure how to go about getting GMFBridge to work in C++ CLR forms. Would i just call [DllImport] on everything from GMFBridge?

Answer (score 0):

Or I could just add a reference to the dll in the CLR project "Common Solutions." Because that totally never came up in Google searches and did not know the Add Reference option was moved there. >_>